# Format string to search engine style in R/Shiny

Tags: r, regex, shiny

I am working on a seemingly simple problem that nevertheless seems to be an annoying regex calculation.

I am designing a shiny app that allows users to search a database for strings and count the number of string matches.

From the stringr package, my ultimate call is:

```
str_count(text, pattern=REGEX(user_input))
```

My goal is to transform the user input into an appropriate regex - while allowing the user to input the data in standard search term format.

So the following user input:

```
artist picasso "picasso painting" france
```

should be formed into the following regex:

```
artist|picasso|picasso painting|france
```

Where the solution knows to treat "picasso painting" as one word due to the quotes.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please show the code you have so far. Right now, there are too many aspects of the task you are working on that are unknown: 1) What are the requirements for the user input? Should it just be whitespace separated entries with words inside double quotes representing one item? 2) Is that just plain text or regex pattern? 3) Can there be non-word chars? 4) Are you going to collect the matches, or just count occurrences? It is important, as `pic|pic here` will not match `pic here`.

Comment: Thank you Wiktor.  At the moment my code is quite sparse, just getting the inputs from Shiny's textInput function parsed correctly to send to str_count().  Per your questions: 1. Yes.  This is just white space separated entries with words inside double quotes representing them.  2. Yes I need non-word chars. 3. For now I am not collecting matches, I'm just counting them.  Thanks again.

Comment: Please check my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a base R solution:

```
regex.escape <- function(string) {
  gsub("([][{}()+*^${|\\\\?])", "\\\\\\1", string)
}

sort.by.length.desc <- function (v) v[order( -nchar(v)) ] 

s <- "artist picasso \"picasso (painting)\" france zoo"
keys <- c(t(read.table(text=s, header=FALSE)))          # Read in the values
keys <- sort.by.length.desc(keys)                       # Sort the values
pattern = paste(regex.escape(keys), collapse="|")       # Create the pattern
## Test
## cat(pattern, sep="\n")                               # This shows the regex pattern
txt <- "The artist was born in france and named picasso picasso (painting)"
length(unlist(gregexpr(pattern, txt)))                  # Count the number of occurrences
[1] 4
```

See the [R demo](http://ideone.com/rhcAsH). There are 4 matches, thus, the output is `4`.

**Details**:

- The `regex.escape`  function escapes the most important chars that a regex engine may interpret as special characters
- The `sort.by.length.desc` orders the items of the character vector by character vector length in a descending order
- The `c(t(read.table(text=s, header=FALSE)))` reads the user input and stores as a character vector in `keys`
- The `pattern = paste(regex.escape(keys), collapse="|")` creates a pattern with alternation operators (looks like [`picasso \(painting\)|picasso|artist|france|zoo`](https://regex101.com/r/XmVrYP/1/), `cat(pattern, sep="\n")` displays the resulting pattern as a literal string)
- The `length(unlist(gregexpr(pattern, txt)))` line counts occurrences of a match using base R `gregexpr` function.

Answer (score 0):

Split it up by doing global match using `"[^"]*"|\S+`.
Blindly remove leading/trailing double quotes `^"|"$`.
Push the matches into an array.
Sort the array longest on top (descending ?).
Replace each element's metachars `([\[$^()*+|{}-\\])` with `\\$1`.
Finally, join the elements together with an alternation `|`.